# How to add form data to dynamic string in php codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, sms, codeigniter-3

PHP -> CODEIGNITER

Tables
- users [customers information]
- sms gateway [sms gateway configuration apiKey, sender code]
- sms template [ pre-approved dynamic templates eg, visitor to office]

Form
- fullname [input field] = SHREYAS
- Phone [input field] = 123456789
- service [dynamic dropdowm from services table] = ABC
- remark = QWERTY

** Form Submitted **
1) $post = $this->input->post(); [PHP codeigniter syntax for controller]

2) $data[] = $post[]; [all the form data is stored in array called data]

3) inserted data to db [visitors]

** sending sms to visitor **
1) $users_id = $this->session->userdata('users_id'); [PHP codeigniter syntax for getting users_id from session]

2) get_sms_gateway_details [of customer where users_id = $users_id]

3) $sms_content[users_id,sms_gateway_id,TITLE] // getting the template with users_id sms_gateway_id and title("visitors")

4) $sms_content is added in foreach loop to get visitors template message as string in $message

******** Problem I am facing ********

5) $message = Dear '.$post['fullname'],', Your request for '.$service_name.' is in progress. Our team will get back to you soon. Have a Great Day !!!. mob: +91

0000000000.
("this is the sms template used for visitors in which $post['fullname'] should be SHREYAS and $service_name = ABC" which was submitted in form above)

6) Final output required = Dear SHREYAS, Your request for ABC is in progress. Our team will get back to you soon. Have a Great Day !!!. mob: +91 0000000000.

7) later this will be added to sms_data_array[] and will be sent using PHP CRUL method

Comment: please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I understand your concern but issue i am facing needed more explanation. anyway thank you for addressing the subject